# Adding View of MVC component to another MVC component

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I have a custom `UITableCell` view and I need to add a subview to it. However that subview is an instance of a `UIView` subview that has a `UIViewController` associated with it and I would like to stay within the MVC paradigm. How can I add successfully add this view?

Thanks

Comment: Does your subview holds reference to `UIViewController`?

Comment: @tailec It doesn't but it can do, why?

Comment: So how your `UIViewController` is associated with your subview?

Comment: Its through the storyboard, the view outlet of the `UIViewController` is connected to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You will stay within MVC when you add subview to `UITableViewCell`.

Add your subview to your `UITableViewCell` subclass, create outlet and use it in your ViewController.